# How can I get GADM level 0 (countries) shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, gadm

When downloading GADM data from their website (https://gadm.org), It is highly suggested to download it country by country. I would need the whole world at once with only level 0 geometries.

The global dataset provided (https://gadm.org/data.html) does not include all the level 0 geometries but only the smallest subsets of each country.

Is there a simple way to get the level 0 data for all countries?

Comment: All the GADM level 0 data I've ever seen was for all countries. Please [Edit] the Question to specify who "they" are that requires singleton selection.

Comment: See edit.......

Comment: There are a lot of sites with GDAM data.  A URL is called for.

Comment: I don't understand "without internal detail". Are you wanting land mass polygons?

Comment: I assume you mean gadm.org, and was surprised to learn you are correct: there are no multipolygons that cover entire countries, only 1st level administrative districts. You might see if openstreetmaps.org can help

Comment: Dissolve the polygons based on the country name.  The resulting feature class will show only the outlines of the country and not the administrative areas inside the countries.

Comment: @GBG That's really ugly though. Someone should suggest to gadm.org to include "level 0" administrative areas aka countries.

Comment: Good idea about combining the polygons, but it's nuts that there's not the country level info someplace.  This question is about GADM, but Natural Earth does have the plain country data ready to go at a few different levels of detail.

Comment: There's a new version of GADM coming out tomorrow, maybe they fixed it?